# ps -fu $USER ... but shorter

Tags: ps

I like `ps -fu $USER` it displays all processes of the current user and displays enough information per process.

But I am lazy and would like to have a shorter solution.

I know aliases and they are not a solution.

How to get (roughly) the same output as `ps -fu $USER` but with typing less characters?

Comment: Why are you opposed to using an alias? It's the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: @NasirRiley since I work on a lot of different servers. Yes, we have a central configuration management. I could use it and deploy aliases on all machines, but ... I like to stick to the standard. I don't have the same configuration management for the servers which I manage in spare time....

Comment: Adding an alias in the form of pf would be a rather negligible change but I can understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 6):

You can use BSD-style selection switches:

```
ps x
```

lists all the current user’s processes, with nearly as much information as `ps -f`.

When using BSD-style switches, `ps` defaults to “all the current user’s processes with a terminal”; the `x` option lifts the terminal restriction.

`ps xu` or `ps xl` will show additional information (the former is “user-oriented”, the latter “BSD long format”).